# Cannot SSH to github.com after changing to static IP

Tags: networking, ssh, mac-osx, static-ip, github

I've been using github.com for a long time, but just had my ISP switch my home internet to a static IP and now I can't SSH to github.

**What happens with SSH?**

The id_ed25519 key has just been re-generated.  SSH just stops:

```
$ ssh -T -F ~/.ssh/config git@github.com -vvv

OpenSSH_8.1p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/xxxx/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/xxx/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to github.com port 22.
```

Wireshark shows it's not getting any return packets at all:

[an screen capture of my wireshark showing TCP Retransmissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTiV5.png)

**So maybe SSH isn't allowed?**

Maybe!   But I can ssh to AWS EC2 instances fine from the same command prompt.   No issues at all.

**What else have I tried?**

I can use SSH over HTTPS.  For example, this...

```
ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
```

...works fine and I can connect.   But I need to know WHY plain ol' port 22 isn't working for me anymore.

**What changed?**

I asked my ISP to assign me a static IP.  They've done this. It worked. Connections out from devices on my network appear to be coming from this new static IP they've assigned.

**Content of ssh config**

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

And as added bonus,

```
$ git config --list
credential.helper=osxkeychain
user.name=xxxx
user.email=xxx.xxx@xxx.com
core.autocrlf=input
```

Comment: Have you rebooted your router after the static IP was assigned? What is the output of `tcptraceroute github.com 22`? You can install it with homebrew: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/tcptraceroute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use tcp traceroute**

Following Tero Kilkanen's advice, I installed tcptraceroute, which led to resolution of the problem.  Edit: I wanted to add that I hadn't used `traceroute` because I knew it used ICMP protocol and wouldn't be necessarily be routed the same way as my TCP SSH packets.     So `tcptraceroute` was new to me and I think it's going to be very useful!

*1). Install tcptraceroute*

This is on Mac, so I used homebrew to install the suggested formula: formulae.brew.sh/formula/tcptraceroute:

```
$ brew install tcptraceroute
```

*2). Running tcptraceroute*

```
$ sudo tcptraceroute github.com 22
```

I've included a snippet of trace that shows it stops with the ISP:

```
 6  bundle-ether10.win-core10.melbourne.telstra.net (203.50.11.123)  26.865 ms  26.183 ms  27.529 ms
 7  bundle-ether2.fli-core10.adelaide.telstra.net (203.50.6.228)  34.738 ms  32.591 ms  37.021 ms
 8  bundle-ether1.fli-edge901.adelaide.telstra.net (203.50.11.155)  33.344 ms  33.840 ms  32.964 ms
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
```

*3). Resolution with ISP*

Before phoning the ISP, I checked the account settings.  Disabling the default parental controls did the trick - ssh to github.com is restored!

The rules blocked only youtube.com and that wasn't working.   It seems likely that the ISP's reboot of the connection after assigning the static IP caused a re-evaluation of the configured parental control rules.

No idea why https to github.com would be allowed and not ssh (or even why github.com was blocked), but there we go - problem solved.